# Caffe with multiple loss layers

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

When playing with Caffe, I observe that we can have several loss layers in the prototxt file.
I believe that Caffe will compute the gradient from the combined loss and use it to adjust the weights of the network.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.
If you look closely, you'll notice that loss layers has a parameter [`loss_weight`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L319-L322), the total loss (to be derived for back-propagation) is the *weighted* sum of the multiple losses.

Comment: Hi, did you tried with the parameter before? Its schemes of loss_weight is similar to Deeply-Supervised Nets paper. Is it right?